# go/types finding if struct implements interface

Tags: parsing, variables, go, interface

OK so looking at using go/types, go/parser... an so forth to generate some code; but need to identify all structs that implement a specific interface which I have figured out, however, if the struct definition on the struct function it does not match using types.Implements.

OK the code examples:

**Getting the interface**

```
package ifacepkg

const interfacePkg = `package ifacepkg

type MyInterface interface {
    MyFunction() error
}
`

func getIface() *types.Interface {

fset := token.NewFileSet()

f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "iface.go", interfacePkg, 0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

config := &types.Config{
    Error: func(e error) {
        fmt.Println(e)
    },
    Importer: importer.Default(),
}

info := types.Info{
    Types: make(map[ast.Expr]types.TypeAndValue),
    Defs:  make(map[*ast.Ident]types.Object),
    Uses:  make(map[*ast.Ident]types.Object),
}

pkg, e := config.Check("genval", fset, []*ast.File{f}, &info)
if e != nil {
    fmt.Println(e)
}

return pkg.Scope().Lookup("MyInterface").Type().Underlying().(*types.Interface)
}
```

**Test File**

```
package test

import "ifacepkg"

// User struct
type User struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}

func (u User) MyFunction() error {
    return nil
}

var _ ifacepkg.MyInterface = &User{}
```

**Loading Test File & trying to see if User implements MyInterface**

```
fset := token.NewFileSet()

pkgs, e := parser.ParseDir(fset, "./test", nil, 0)
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
    // return
}

var astf []*ast.File

for _, pkg := range pkgs {
    fmt.Printf("package %v\n", pkg.Name)
    for fn, f := range pkg.Files {
        fmt.Printf("file %v\n", fn)
        astf = append(astf, f)
    }
}

config := &types.Config{
    Error: func(e error) {
        fmt.Println(e)
    },
    Importer: importer.Default(),
}

info := types.Info{
    Types: make(map[ast.Expr]types.TypeAndValue),
    Defs:  make(map[*ast.Ident]types.Object),
    Uses:  make(map[*ast.Ident]types.Object),
}

pkg, e := config.Check(path, fset, astf, &info)
if e != nil {
    fmt.Println(e)
}

vIface := getIface()
fmt.Println(vIface)

scope := pkg.Scope()

    for _, name := range scope.Names() {

        obj := scope.Lookup(name)

        _, ok := obj.Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)
        imp := types.Implements(obj.Type(), vIface)

        fmt.Println(obj.Name(), ok, imp)
    }
```

OK so fmt.Println(obj.Name(), ok, imp) prints User true true all good! however if I change the source file function from

```
func (u User) MyFunction() error {
```

to

```
func (u *User) MyFunction() error {
```

it now prints User true false

so the function types.Implements is reporting that User does not implement MyInterface, which is not true.

So my question is: Is there an issue with the type.Implements method or is there something I have to do to my object prior to calling that function.

**Answer**

ok to solve my own issue changing final portion of code to

```
scope := pkg.Scope()

for _, name := range scope.Names() {

    obj := scope.Lookup(name)

    _, ok := obj.Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)
    ptr := types.NewPointer(obj.Type())
    imp := types.Implements(ptr.Underlying(), vIface)

    fmt.Println(obj.Name(), ok, imp)
}
```

which works with both Pointer and non-pointer recievers

Answer (score 1):

What your compiler is telling you is true. *Type != Type in Go. If you want `*User` to implement your interface then the methods receiver has to be `*User` and if you want it to be `User` then it needs to be `User`. I don't really know how else to explain it... Go's type system is strict and those aren't the same. You can see this more practically if you have `(u *User) MyFunction()` defined for the pointer type do `ptr := &MyUser` then check if `MyUser` and `ptr` implement the interface, `ptr` will, `MyUser` will not.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I am familiar with pointers and go's type system, I guess I was just getting hung up on the go/types package as I thought that the Object aka *types.Struct is not the struct User itself but a definition of it.

anyways the real question now is how do I deal with it; I think I may have solved my own issue by using https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/types#NewPointer and then should be able to use that from there to compare... will post answer when I get a chance to try it.

Comment: @joeybloggs I'll look over your code more and perhaps provide some sample code specific to that. But in general, you just have to be conscious of whether you have a pointer or value. You can get either easily enough with the address of operate - `&` to get the address of a value. So like if you have a value of type `T` you can get `*T` by doing `ptr := &T`. And if you have the pointer type `*T` then you can 'dereference' it which returns the value at the address and it will be of type `T`. It would be like `value := *T`

Comment: ok to solve my own issue changing final portion of code to 
    scope := pkg.Scope()

    for _, name := range scope.Names() {

        obj := scope.Lookup(name)

        _, ok := obj.Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)
        ptr := types.NewPointer(obj.Type())
 imp := types.Implements(ptr.Underlying(), vIface)

        fmt.Println(obj.Name(), ok, imp)
    }

which works with both Pointer and non-pointer recievers